# как работает анимация в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

пробовал понять читая статьи,не получилось!Прошу объяснить по простому на примере:есть StackPane с именем Mpane нужно увеличить его размер с допустим 1080 x 720 до 2048 x 1080,помощь не помешала-бы...за ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node node = mPane; //не пишите имена переменных с заглавной буквы, так не принято

//анимация в течении  полутора секунд
Duration animationDuration = new Duration( 1500 );

Timeline timeline = new TimeLine(
    //далее перечисляем ключевые точки анимации
    //порядок не имеет значения

    //стартовые значения, взаимодействуем с pref параметрами,
    //т.к. реальные readonly
    new KeyFrame( Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue( node.prefWidthProperty(), 1080.0 ) ),
    new KeyFrame( Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue( node.prefHeightProperty(), 720.0 ) ),

    //конечные значения
    new KeyFrame( animationDuration, new KeyValue( node.prefWidthProperty(), 2048.0 ) ),
    new KeyFrame( animationDuration, new KeyValue( node.prefHeightProperty(), 1080.0 ) )      
);

timeline.play();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!А можно уточнить почему у меня появляется ошибка: new KeyFrame( animationDuration, new KeyValue( node.prefHeightProperty(), 1080.0 ) )      
  symbol:   method prefHeightProperty()
  location: variable node of type Node
4 errors

Comment: @AseTry По приведенному комментарию сложно судить. Предлагаю либо дополните вопрос с развернутым `stackTrace` и кодом, либо ( что лучше ) задайте новый вопрос

Comment: спасибо уже разобрался!